# How to make sure one css file does not override another one?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in my project, and I'm also using one css file which is borrowed from one open source project and also based on bootstrap.

In this css file, it has:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0
}
```

My html is very simple:

```
<div class="special"><div class="container">...</div></div>
```

What I want is for `container` inside `special` div, I use the `container` from bootstrap, like this:

```
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

For other containers, use the one from above css.

Comment: Declare your styles in `.special .container {}`

Comment: Copy bootstrap container definition to `.special .container {}` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assign id or special class to special div and in css use descendant selector or child selector like given below.

```
<div id="divSpecial">
<div class="container"></div>
</div>


#divSpecial .container {
```

}

```
<div class="divSpecial">
<div class="container"></div>
</div>


.divSpecial .container {
```

}